# GoF Design Patterns in TOGAF enterprise continuum

Tags: design-patterns, togaf

Where would you classify the GoF Design Patterns in the TOGAF enterprise continuum? In Architecture or Solution? Foundation segment or somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its part of solution building blocks: Foundation Solutions are highly generic concepts, tools, products, services, and solution components that are the fundamental providers of capabilities.  (in otherwords all foundations are generic not specific to solution and GOF is part of foundation)